# Can I get all needed data rigth away in a single query, with relations?

Tags: php, mysql, api, yii2

I'm trying to optimize my SQL queries. I'm actually using yii2 framework, for manipulating data. I can query needed data  with relations in MySQL console and query will be like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user u
 LEFT JOIN relation_user_shop rus ON rus.userId = u.id
 LEFT JOIN shop s ON s.id = rus.shopId
 ORDER BY u.id LIMIT 20
```

It's query me right data, which I needed, but it works only in mysql. When I'm trying to return data into yii2, I get mixed id(primary keys for both related tabled: user, shop) and other data mixing too. I know, that I can it in 3 times, one by one:

```
1. get user
2. select shop ids in junction table
3. query data from shop, and concate with user object
```

Is it possible to do in ONE query?

Comment: Show me what you have tried

Comment: Just give up your eyes to top of the page, and you will see MySQL query, which I tryed, and you will see ALL info about this issue.

Comment: I don't know why you giving me kindergarten's solutions, which uses foreach and other loops. It's question about optimization and performance

Comment: You can use `findBySql` method of the `User` model to completely copy your MySQL query.

Comment: update your question and add  also the php code where you use the query

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  a strict controll over the query and obtain all the column you need  managed  by different column name alais when equale between the tables
a simple (and performant way) is base on db->createCommand

queryAll()  return an array ob object that contain all the rows selected

```
$q =    'SELECT u.col1
  , u.col2
  , u.col3
  , rus.col1 as rus_col1
  , rus.col2 as rus_col2
  , s.col1 as s_col1
  , s.col2 as s_col2 
  FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN relation_user_shop rus ON rus.userId = u.id
  LEFT JOIN shop s ON s.id = ;';

$models =   Yii::$app->db->createCommand( $q )->queryAll();
```